# How to write a session based executor that only runs one thing in that session at a time?

Tags: java, multithreading

In nio, you can get data off many sockets and you need to feed this data **in order** downstream to SSL Engine or perhaps an http parser.  I have been thinking about creating a SessionExecutor with an interface something like so (that would have many threads yet still keep data from same key in order)

```
 public void execute(Object key, Runnable r);
```

I would also like one key NOT to be tied to one thread from the pool of threads.  As I receive stuff from key=1, runnable=A, B, C, these runnables must run A, then B, then C but ideally don't have to run on the same thread(ie. we don't want one key that hashes to the same thread to starve out another key on that same hash/thread).  We would like however that the B runnable does not run until the A runnable is done running.

This ends up being a very interesting algorithm problem.  If I end up with 1000 sockets, I am not sure I want to have 1000 queues either.  If I only have 1 queue, then I need to look at all incoming runnables and their key and make sure that key is not runnable and may have to traverse the queue every time.

I was hoping to make it a bit faster than that though.

Better yet, does something like this already exist?  I don't happen to know of anything offhand.

Edit: As I think more about this, I tend to wonder if there is a good algorithm/data structure that could support something like this where you have one queue and N channels in the queue with some sort of special ordering.  Or if this would be a mix of data structures to acheive this.  I am thinking I need some sort of mix right now.

Answer (score 0):

I took a stab at this and came up with something like this

https://github.com/deanhiller/webpieces/blob/master/core-util/src/main/java/org/webpieces/util/threading/SessionExecutorImpl.java

I still wonder if something else could be a little more performant....not sure, but premature optimization being the root of all evil and all that...I will go with this for now.